# Temporary Storage in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have come across one requirement in which I have to use one token, which will be getting from 3rd party and need to reuse this token for different transaction until it gets expired. I don't want to keep this token in database. Is there any way by which I can keep the token in the temporary storage of WSO2 ESB and and reuse it and whenever required, I also need to update it from WSO2 ESB with any logic anytime.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Shri

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea, because you somehow integrate a statefull logic. Could it be that you get the token in the query each time, then try to validate it instead of storing it "in the ESB". By the way how is the token initially set? Maybe you should as well have a look on business process server

Answer (score 0):

You can use this js script to save a global value and reuse it in different transactions :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[                         
    var curValue = mc.getEnvironment().getServerContextInformation().getProperty("MyValue");
    if (curValue == null) {             
        curValue = 0;           
    } else {
        curValue++;
    }
    mc.getEnvironment().getServerContextInformation().addProperty("MyValue",curValue);
    mc.setProperty("CurrentValue",curValue);
]]></script>
```

You can get current value inside your mediation with get-property('CurrentValue')

Value is lost when your shutdown / restart the ESB

Comment: Thanks Jean & Nicolas!   @Jean - if we have more than one node (cluster) then this property value will not be same for both node, I believe. Looks like we don't have any storage like database in wso2 ESB

Comment: Sure you have a storage like database in WSO2 ESB, have a look to https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database

Comment: You can create, update and read value in registry. Create / update with js :  mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().newResource("gov:/trunk/test/MyValue",false); mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource("gov:/trunk/test/MyValue",0);      read inside your mediation with get-property('gov:/trunk/test/MyValue')